# Delete all files in a directory whose name do not match a line in a file list

Tags: files, find

I have a directory with 1000+ files. In a text file, I have about 50 filenames, one per line. I'd like to delete all the files in the directory whose filenames don't correspond with an entry on the list. What's the best way to do this? I started a shell script, but couldn't determine the proper command to determine in the filename is on the list. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I realize that any question asking how to delete files must be taken with great care. 
My first answer was too hasty I didn't take the fact that the filelist could be malformed to be used with egrep. I edited the answer to reduce that risk.*

That should work for the files that has no space in the name:

First rebuild your filelist to be sure to match the exact file name:

```
sed -e 's,^,^,' -e 's,$,$,'  filelist  > newfilelist
```

build the rm commands

```
cd your_directory
ls | egrep -vf newfilelist   | xargs -n 1 echo rm  >  rmscript
```

Check if the rm script suits you  (You can do it with "vim" or "less").
Then perform the action :

```
sh -x rmscript
```

If the files have spaces in their name (if the files have the `"` in the name then this will not work) :

```
ls | egrep -vf newfilelist  | sed 's,^\(.*\)$,rm "\1",' > rmscript
```

of course the filelist should not be in the same directory!

EDITED :

The Nathan's file list contained names that were matching all the files in the directory  (like "html" matches "bob.html").  So nothing was deleted because `egrep -vf` absorbed all the stream. I added a command to put a "^" and a "$" around each file name. I was lucky here that Nathan's file list was correct. Would have it been DOS formatted with CR-LF ended lines or with additional spaces, no files would have been preserved by the egrep and all been deleted.

Comment: When I run the preview command, I get one line with "rm". When I run the actual command, I get an error message about missing arguments for rm. Do I need special syntax to use the results from ls | egrep in the xargs input?

Comment: @Nathan you must cd to your directory first. No special syntaxt. `ls` provides the directory file names, `egrep -vf filelist` filter your 50 file names. I'm afraid you deleted all your files.

Comment: @Emamanuel I'm running the command from the directory that contains files to be deleted.

Comment: @Nathan are all your files deleted ?

Comment: no, they're still there.

Comment: @Nathan ok for now you can use `ls | egrep -vf filelist`  what is the output ?

Comment: Nothing is returned... Does the fileslist have to contain the full path or just the filename?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14237/discussion-between-emmanuel-and-nathan)

Answer (score 1):

Pre-construct the arguments to `find`:

```
{
  read -r
  keep=( -name "$REPLY" ) # no `-o` before the first one.
  while read -r; do
    keep+=( -o -name "$REPLY" )
  done
} < file_list.txt
find . -type f ! \( "${keep[@]}" \) -exec echo rm {} +
```

Use the `echo` parts to see what would be constructed. Remove the `echo` parts to actually run it.

#### Update: Demonstration:

```
##
# Demonstrate what files exist for testing.
# Show their whitespace:
~/foo $ printf '"%s"\n' *
" op"
" qr"
"abc"
"def"
"gh "
"ij "
"k l"
"keep"
"m n"

##
# Show the contents of the "keep" file,
# Including its whitespace:
~/foo $ cat -e keep
keep$
abc$
gh $
k l$
 op$

##
# Execute the script:
~/foo $ { read -r; keep=( -name "$REPLY" ); while read -r ; do keep+=( -o -name "$REPLY" ); done } < keep
~/foo $ find . -type f ! \( "${keep[@]}" \) -exec rm {} +

##
# Show what files remain:
~/foo $ printf '"%s"\n' *
" op"
"abc"
"gh "
"k l"
"keep"
```

Comment: i like this one best as it removes the need fore filelist

Comment: +1 from me, although it doesn't deal very well with spaces. Perhaps some single quotes (`'`) should be added i.e. `keep=( -name \'"$REPLY"\' )` and `keep+=( -o -name \'"$REPLY"\' )`.

Comment: the above is dangerous, because you can delete accidentally files.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu doesn't it? I added a demo showing that it deals very well with whitespace.

Comment: @davidva Under what circumstances? Any time you automate deleting things you run the risk of making a mistake, but within the parameters of the question I think my demo proves this approach is sound.

Comment: @kojiro, `echo find...` said something else.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu `echo` can be misleading. The `echo` before the `rm` shows what would really happen. The first `echo` was redundant, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
mylist=(${(f)"$(<filelist)"})
print -rl -- *(.^e_'(($mylist[(Ie)$REPLY]))'_)
```

It reads the lines of `filelist` in an array and then uses [glob qualifiers/`e`string](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) to glob/select only the file names not present in the array: the `.` selects only regular files (add `D` if your list contains dotfiles) and the negated `^e_'expression'_` further selects only those for which the expression returns false, i.e. if their name (`$REPLY`) [is not an element of the array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags).
If you're happy with the result replace `print -rl` with `rm` to actually remove the files:

```
rm -- *(.^e_'(($mylist[(Ie)$REPLY]))'_)
```

To select & remove files recursively, use the `*/**` glob with [`${REPLY:t}`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) glob modifier:

```
rm -- */**(.^e_'(($mylist[(Ie)${REPLY:t}]))'_)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the contents of the directory into a file like so:

```
cd <somedirectory>
ls >> filelist
```

Open filelist with a text editor, and remove all the files except the ones **YOU WANT TO DELETE**.  That's bolded because it's the opposite approach to the answer above

Try this:

```
while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; 
echo $p
done < filelist
```

If you see your list of files output to the screen replace echo with `rm -v`, like so:

```
while read p || [[ -n $p ]]; 
rm -v $p
done < filelist
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the below script.

1. Initially I am finding all the files that are present inside the
   directory and storing the output to another file `all_files`.
2. We have a file which has the list of files that should **NOT** be
   deleted (`not_to_be_deleted_files`).
3. I am adding the file names `not_to_be_deleted_files` and
   `files_to_be_deleted` to the end of `not_to_be_deleted_files` as we
   need these 2 files.
4. Now, I am finding the files that needs to be deleted using linux
   `join` command and redirecting the output to `files_to_be_deleted`
   file.
5. Now, in the final while loop I am reading all the file names in
   `files_to_be_deleted` and removing the files mentioned in that file
   name.

The script is as below.

```
find /home/username/directory -type f | sed 's/.*\///' > all_files
echo all_files >> not_to_be_deleted_files
echo not_to_be_deleted_files >> not_to_be_deleted_files
echo files_to_be_deleted >> not_to_be_deleted_files
join -v 1 <(sort all_files_listed) <(sort files_not_to_be_deleted) >   files_to_be_deleted
while read file
rm  "$file"
done < files_to_be_deleted
```

**P.S**: Probably, if you wish this to be saved as a script and run it, you can add the script name also using `echo scriptname >> not_to_be_deleted_files`.

Though it is not required, I prefer to do it because there will be no regrets later. I tested for a small set of files and it worked in my system. However, if you want to be sure, try in a `test` directory first and then remove the files in the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the list as a source, to move all files in the list to a fresh, new and empty save-dir.
- Compare the number of files in the list and the number of saved files.
- If both match, delete all unsaved files with your favorite method.
- Move the saved files back.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a safer and much, much faster approach because I had 18.000 files in the list! I needed to clean up images in a large Drupal installation.

Deleting all the files that are not in the list is the same as keeping only those that are in the list. So I decided to actually copy the files from the list to another location, but copying 20 GB of files would take up too much space and be very slow as well. So the trick is to copy the files as `hardlinks` instead, using the `-l` option of `cp`. This takes up almost no space and is very fast. Additionally, since I needed to preserve the directory structure, I used the `--parents` option.

Here is an excerpt from my file list:

```
1px.png
misc/feed.png
modules/file/icons/x-office-presentation.png
modules/file/icons/x-office-spreadsheet.png
newsletter.png
sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/devil_smile.png
sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/regular_smile.png
sites/default/files/009313_PwC_banner_CBS_Observer_180x246px.jpg
```

So an example line would be, with temp being the destination:

```
cp -l --parents 'misc/feed.png' temp
```

This will create this structure:

```
temp
  misc
    feed.png
```

Note that the destinaton must be in the same file system as the source for hardlinks to work.

The next step is to construct the script:

```
sed -e "s,^,cp -l --parents '," -e "s,$,' /some/where/temp," filelist > newfilelist
```

Now, presuming you already created the empty dir /some/where/temp, you can copy the files like this:

```
sh newfilelist 2> missing_files
```

Note how errors end up in `missing_files`. The added bonus of this approach is that you will get a list of files from the original list that actually *don't* exist!

After running the script, temp will contain only those files that are in the file list, but without deleting anything and without taking up additional space. If you are satisfied with the result, you can delete all the orginal files including the subfolders.

Finally, move the files and folders from temp back to the original location.

For the 18.000 files it took only a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Safe, simple.

`cd` to directory.

Create a temp directory.

```
mv *.yourExlusionSelector.* ./temp
rm *
mv ./temp ./
rm -rf ./temp
```

done.

Comment: Welcome to the site. While your approach will work if the names on the list mentioned by the OP are the result of a simple pattern matching - which may very well be the case - please note that the OP stated that the filenames to exclude are stored in a specific file; you may want to expand your answer so as to read the exclusion patterns from that file instead of relying on one static pattern, or having to type-copy potentially multiple patterns to the console.