# Remove old files in a directory except files present in an exception file

Tags: shell-script, find, ksh

I am writing a shell script to delete old files (older than 60 days) in a directory except few files and these file names are maintained in an exception file present in another directory.

I know the following command works for one exception file but i need to check a list of exception files

```
find . ! -name 'file.txt' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: related: [Delete all files in a directory whose name do not match a line in a file list](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127268)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your files have sane names (i.e. they don't have embedded newlines), something like this should work:

```
find . -mtime +60 | fgrep -v -x -f exceptions.txt | xargs -d '\n' rm -f
```

Replace `rm -f` with `ls -1` for a dry run first.  Put paths exactly as they are printed by `find` in `exceptions.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is fgrep taking output from find command and eliminating the files present in exceptions.txt and sending the result to rm command ?

Comment: `find` prints a list of files, one per line.  `fgrep` filters out the files in `exceptions.txt`.  `xargs ... rm -f`  removes the files.

Comment: Works perfectly !! Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `find` has an option like this, you could build a command using `printf` and your exclude list:

```
find . -name "*.txt" $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat file.txt)) -mtime +60 -exec rm -f {} +
```

`file.txt` will have list of files to exclude in `find` command.