# rsync-like --delete functionality with wget (not wget's --delete-after)

Tags: rsync, wget, delete

**Background:** my particular problem, which gave rise to this question, is as follows. I'm a slackware linux user, and on 23-March-2019 mirrored their distribution with the following command

```
wget -r -np -R "index.html*" https://mirror.slackbuilds.org/slackware/slackware64-current/
```

Then recently, 29-Aug-2019, I refreshed/updated my local mirror simply by adding the `-N` option to the above command. But that resulted in my mirror containing many, many "duplicate" older and newer versions of the same packages, just with different version numbers, e.g.,

```
SDL2_mixer-2.0.4-x86_64-1.txz
SDL2_mixer-2.0.4-x86_64-2.txz
libcddb-1.3.2-x86_64-5.txz
libcddb-1.3.2-x86_64-6.txz
```

etc (and I mean ***lots*** of etc's:)

**Question:** So what I really want to do is something like

```
rsync -av --delete https://mirror.slackbuilds.org/slackware/slackware64-current/ my-slackware64-mirror-directory/
```

That `rsync --delete` would have automatically deleted all the older versions from my mirror-directory that no longer exist on slackbuilds.org. However, I don't have any kind of account on slackbuilds, and therefore can't (as far as I know) run rsync to get files from it. Is there any wget way to accomplish the same thing? Or any way at all? Thanks.

**Edit:   lengthy reply to @roaima's comment...** 
    Thanks for the suggestion, @roaima. And now that you mention it, yup, there is such a file in the top-level directory, predictably named FILELIST.TXT   But I'm not sure how to use it as input to some procedure that would --delete the older files not in the current filelist. Could you point me to a manpage, or whatever, that describes how to do that? Thanks again.

Also, that FILELIST.TXT is in an   `ls -al`   format that might not be the easiest for canned procedures to parse (although I can probably write a small C program to convert it to any suitable format). A few typical lines from the file are

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1637708 2019-08-15 18:06 ./slackware64/a/bash-5.0.009-x86_64-1.txz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       163 2019-08-15 18:06 ./slackware64/a/bash-5.0.009-x86_64-1.txz.asc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       226 2018-10-17 03:06 ./slackware64/a/bin-11.1-x86_64-3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     39576 2018-10-17 03:06 ./slackware64/a/bin-11.1-x86_64-3.txz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       163 2018-10-17 03:06 ./slackware64/a/bin-11.1-x86_
```

And very relevant to your apparently-prescient suggestion, the first few lines of the file are the remark

```
Wed Aug 28 21:44:15 UTC 2019
Here is the file list for this directory.  If you are using a 
mirror site and find missing or extra files in the disk 
subdirectories, please have the archive administrator refresh
the mirror.
```

Comment: Is there a list of current packages that you could use to trim the set that you have copied?

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the suggestion. I've added an Edit at the bottom of the question with a lengthy reply. In short, yes, there's a list. But what's the procedure to use that list to sync up the actual files with it? Thanks again.

Comment: @roaima googling found a couple of ways to use such a list, e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127268/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/830776/ But none that I found seem to --recurse below the pwd. And that slackware mirror has lots of subdirectories, with the filelist containing full paths to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: I can't currently test any code I'm suggesting. As always, please test carefully before building this code into a proper script.</sub>

Given it's a package list (and therefore having simple filenames without spaces, etc.), you can probably pick out the filenames with some very straightforward code

```
# Get last item from each line of FILELIST
awk '{print $NF}' FILELIST | sort >weblist

# Generate a list of your files
find -type f -print | sort >mylist

# Compare results
comm -23 mylist weblist >diffs

# Remove old files
xargs -r echo rm -fv <diffs
```

As you can see, you'll need to remove the final `echo` to allow `rm` to do its work

Furthermore, next time you want to update your mirror, you can modify the `comm` line (by swapping the two file arguments) to find the set of files you *don't* have, and feed those to `wget`.

Comment: Thanks again, roaima. Yeah, that all (each step separately) seems to work, though I haven't tested the last actual rm step yet (and will eventually do it against a copy of the mirror). There's a little bit of symlink goofiness (they're in the original FILELIST, but not the  -type f list), but I can straighten that out for myself. Your basic four steps seem right on the money (but you only get a "check":). And it still strikes me as a little strange that there isn't a straightforward wget --option for this. They've got --mirror, but not the necessary rsync-like --delete for an -N update mirror.

Comment: P.S. Your roaima.co.uk site seems to be down. And with respect to bellringing.org, where the heck's your link to https://poets.org/poem/bells ???:)

Comment: PS reply: I haven't run roaima.co.uk for a few years; I'll remove the link. I ought to link to [Dorothy Sayers](https://epdf.pub/the-nine-tailors.html) too then :-)

Comment: No need to remove the `echo`, just pipe the output to `sh`.  That way, running `./myscript | less` will always **show** you what files it's going to delete, but not actually do it.  A nice dry-run safety feature.  If the user agrees, the user then runs `./myscript | sh` and the files go away. +1 btw.